# matplotlib pcolormesh grid not visible

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know why my grid is not plotted on top of the colormap here.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

Style = 'ggplot'
plt.style.use([Style])

data = np.random.random((40,40))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, zorder=1)
ax.grid(True, zorder=10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plt.rcParams["axes.axisbelow"] = False` to force the grid to be on top. Note that this problem only occurs because of the use of the `"ggplot"` style.

**Example with ggplot style:**

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams["axes.axisbelow"] = False

data = np.random.random((40,40))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, zorder=1)
ax.grid(True, color="crimson", lw=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Example using default style:**

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((40,40))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, zorder=1)
ax.grid(True, color="crimson", lw=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, using imshow also seems to work with ggplot, which is a bit odd but at least its working :)